# simple recursive example - please help me understand recursion

Tags: java, math, recursion

```
    public static int triple(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            total = 3 + triple(n-1);
    System.out.println(total);
    return total;
    }
```

Ok, so I've got this simple recusion example that I just cant seem to grasp, I was hoping someone would be kind enough to walk me through cycle by cycle of how the program gets its output.

Here is what I thought would happen. Lets say `n=5`
So, the program cycles and hits `total = 3 + triple(5-1)`
which i would think would be equal to 7.. which is wrong
the program prints

> 3
>   6
>   9
>   12
>   15

So... then I thought triple must run through again before printing the total... which I believe it does but I just don't understand how it comes to its totals at all then.

Because it would just look like this :

```
3 + triple(4)
       3 + triple(3)
               3 + triple(2)
                       3 + triple(1)
                                =3
```

Can someone explain please, as you can I am very lost!

Comment: i think it would be best for you to step through the program with your debugger.  watch what line comes next, and what the value of n is...

Comment: In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 6):

You're interpreting it slightly wrong.  It's more like this:

```
triple(5) = 3 + triple(4)
triple(4) = 3 + triple(3)
triple(3) = 3 + triple(2)
triple(2) = 3 + triple(1)
triple(1) = 3 + triple(0)
triple(0) = 0
```

Now imagine that `triple(0)`, `triple(1)`, etc. are all individual variables, and solve for `triple(5)` by working your way up.

Answer (score 1):

So wouldn't it work its way down to zero doing (by subtracting 1) then add 3 to each (0 3 6, etc).

This is the output I'm getting:

```
n:5
n:4
n:3
n:2
n:1
n:0
total:3
total:6
total:9
total:12
total:15
```

What it's doing is subtracting one from n each enumeration in, then adding 3 to the now 0-5

Answer (score 1):

Your output should be read as follows:

```
3 = triple(1) = 3+triple(0)
6 = triple(2) = 3+triple(1)
9 = triple(3) = 3+triple(2)
12 = triple(4) = 3+triple(3)
15 = triple(5) = 3+triple(4)
```

It is because triple(n) would invoke triple(n-1) **before** printing out the message. So your triple(5) message will be printed last.

Answer (score 0):

When the execution hits that point, the triple method begins executing again from the start. Once it returns, execution will then resume at the next line. This happens *recursively*.

So the order of execution is something like:

1. if (n == 0)     // n == 5 at this point, condition is false
2. total = 3 + triple(n-1)    // we must calculate triple(4)
3. if (n == 0)     // n == 4 now.
4. total = 3 + triple(n-1)    // we must calculate triple(3)
5. ... etc, until n does == 0:
6. if (n == 0)   // true!
7. return 0      // returns 0
8. total = 3 + 0    // 0 comes from triple(n-1), which just returned 0
9. System.out.println(total);  // prints 3
10. return total;   // returns 3
11. total = 3 + 3;   // again 3 comes from triple(n-1), where n==2
12. System.out.println(total);  // prints 6 this time
13. ... and so on.

Note the function as defined just multiplies the input by 3, and prints the result at each multiple.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int triple(int n)
{

if (n == 0)
return 0;
else
return 3 + triple(n-1);
System.out.println(return);
}
```

Disregard the println(return) its just for understanding purposes. This is how i broke it down to finally get a good grasp on recursive functions/methods.

```
triple(3)
return 3 + triple(3-1)_is_6<---- (return = 9)<--
println(return)

    triple(2)
    return 3 + triple(2-1)_is_3<-- (return = 6)<----
    println(return);

              triple(1)
              return 3 + triple(1-1)_is_0<---- (return = 3)<--
              println(return)

                       triple(0)
                       return 0; is 0 (return = 0)<----
                       (no println for n==0)
```

Thank you all for you help in understanding this. The thing I was not doing was remembering that each triple(n-1) returned its own value that was then calculated into the call above it.

THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

```
triple(0) = 0
triple(1) = 3 + triple(0) i.e. 3+0=3
triple(2) = 3 + triple(1) i.e. 3+3=6
triple(3) = 3 + triple(2) i.e. 3+6=9
triple(4) = 3 + triple(3) i.e. 3+9=12
triple(5) = 3 + triple(4) i.e. 3+12=15
```

Comment: Could you add explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You got confused between triple(n-1) and (n-1). They are different thing, so you cannot just assign the value to n inside triple(n-1) and then add it to 3