# eli5 can't understand this recursion process

Tags: java, recursion

```
public int recursive(int x){
        if(x>10){           
            return x;
        }
        int y = x + 1;
        int r = recursive(y);
        System.out.println(y + " Y" + "  R" + r + "  X " + x);      
        return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new a().recursive(1));
}
```

This is a recursion I made to simplify a different method I could not understand but it has the same code line for line basically. I don't understand what is happening on this line `int r = recursive(y);`. I don't understand what the `return r;` even returns to or how it actively loops. When I system print R, it is always the same value each iteration which throws me off. If I change return `r to return 555` the code still works but just returns `555` to the call from main.

output

```
11 Y  R11  X 10
10 Y  R11  X 9
9 Y  R11  X 8
8 Y  R11  X 7
7 Y  R11  X 6
6 Y  R11  X 5
5 Y  R11  X 4
4 Y  R11  X 3
3 Y  R11  X 2
2 Y  R11  X 1
11
```

Please eli5, I have viewed some recursion videos but they do not use a recursion thats laid out like this, with a return after a recursive call. `int r = recursive(y);`, how does `r` get its value here, and continue the loop, can't figure it out. It says set `r` equal to the return of `recursive(y)`, but the return is `r` itself when the value for `r` has not been set or something?

Another issue I am having is how the system print is running as well, because I thought when the recursive part runs, it instantly restarts the method but it seems the entire method is running and looping

Comment: Jsut curious. What is *eli5*?

Comment: sorry it is short for explain like I am 5

Comment: Can you write the process down on a piece of paper and show us what you have and where you got stuck?

Comment: I tried drawing it but literally don't know where to start with this int r = recursive(y);. I thought r would be 2>3>4>5...but it is always the last value which is 11

Comment: Run with a debugger and you'll understand.

Comment: Well, move your system.out before "r=recursive(y);" and tell us what happenes. U-u-u-h, define r before the system.out, please.

Comment: I did define r before system out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend it looks to me that your recursion breaking conditions is at r>10 so it always breaks at 11 thats the only cause............

suppose you have pass x=1 
then your recursive(1) calls recursive(2), recursive(2) calls recursive(3), recursive(3) calls recursive(4) , recursive(4) calls recursive(5) , recursive(5) calls recursive(6), recursive(6) calls recursive(7), recursive(7) calls recursive(8), recursive(8) calls recursive(9), recursive(9) calls recursive(10), recursive(10) calls recursive(11)

and then recursion breaks and at recursive(11) it returns you 11 at this line `int r = recursive(y); so r becomes 11 and then recursion(10) returns you r and then recursion(9) returns you are and so on ................. for whole stack

Comment: cause of what? I am asking to explain how this recursion is working not what the result is

Comment: There MUST be a breaking conditio

Comment: ya i know but this is the only reason of answer @Thrash Bean

Comment: @Catz n Dogz, My friend i have edited my post with detailed explaination , it will give you the clear picture

Comment: its a lot better thanks but I don't understand the part after recursion breaks and how it goes backwards. I get how I get r now, but after that, it prints a system out for each time the recursion ran, but i dont see the process/logic/why. At least for now I understand where r comes from

Comment: @Catz n Dogz, its like that once R(11) is completed r becomes 11 and the line after int r = recursive(y);  "sysout" is executed and ,R(10) is waiting for R(11) execution because recursion always grows in stack and so on in backward direction

Comment: @Catz n Dogz, have you satisfied

Comment: you are giving good answers i just cant understand it for some reason, I am trying to visualize it like the answers given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533895/simple-recursive-example-please-help-me-understand-recursion?rq=1

Comment: ya it help you and you can also read this http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html

Comment: one more question, I think i got it now though. When recursion breaks and we move down the previous callers, are they PAUSED or STUCK until they get a value for r, so when they get that r = 11, they can continue with the PRINT and RETURN which is 11 for all cases?

Comment: others functions are stuck my friend, you can verified that by removing the break condition from there, so you will get stackoverflow   error your stack will keep going on

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it like a simple loop in this case, it just iterates untill `x` is `>` 10, so ret value of this recusrsion is 11, since it is the first number which is bigger than 10. Since nothing printed before recursive call you print the values in the reversed order, after x becomes 11, and function returns, previos stack frame contains values x == 10, y 10 + 1, and  r contains return value of the functon => 11, same for previos frame and previos .....

Answer (score 1):

When you enter 555, the first condition you have in your function is to return the value if it is greater than 10, so as 555 is greater than 10, it returns directly the value (555).

Now, for the recursion. It's pretty simple, just imagine how the code flows, you enter 1 as a parameter, is it greater than 10? No, so we move to the next line. We assign y the value of x plus 1, so X=1, and Y=2.

And then instead of returning a value, we call again the same function, but instead of 1 as a parameter, we call it with 2 as a parameter (the value of Y). And we start again (that's the point of recursion), but now X=2: Is 2 greater than 10? Now, so we move to the next line. We assign Y the value of the parameter (which is called X) plus 1, so now Y=3 and X=2. Remember that the variables' scope are only in the same function they are declared.

Repeat this, until the parameter goes above 10 (by adding one each time you call the recursive function), and then finally it returns a value! (in the condition where x > 10), so the function finishes and returns the value to the function who called it, which happens to assign that value to R and prints the result.

And so on, finishing each of the called functions that had different values as a parameter (1, 2, 3, etc until 10, as the function each time added one to the parameter and called itself).

I hope this helped you to understand it better, I'm not sure how to explain this simplier. I guess a 5 year old would have some problems to understand this :)

Comment: Thanks, this definitely cleared up how I get the R value, but still leaves me wondering about how the system print actually prints if the recursion should restart the method each time. ' finishing each of the called functions that had different values as a parameter (1, 2, 3, etc until 10, as the function each time added one to the parameter and called itself)' this part is probably why which I still am a confused on

Comment: Oh, that's because the first time you break the condition, Y has a value of 11 (that's why it stopped recurring), so it moves to print the values and then return the value of R, which is also 11. After it returns that value, we move to the function that called this one, where Y has a value of 10, we print the results, and return the value to the calling function... And so on...

Comment: ok i think i finally got it but to be sure, is it going to return 11 to all the previous callers? aka r = recursive(2); r is going to get 11 ? hopefully im right ><. This is because r won't have a value until the base case which is what the other callers are filling in for

Comment: Yes, unless you pass a parameter higher than 11 (the first value that breaks the first condition), you will always end up with 11, if you put a higher value, then this same value will be the result. I think you got it :)